# Python Pandas: Unexplainable NaN values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, quandl

Is there some error that I am doing or is it a fault within pandas or perhaps Quandl?

[image: Is there some error that I am doing or is it a fault within pandas or perhaps Quandl?]

Comment: I got no NaNs when I reproduced it. Maybe try: `quandl_gold_fridays['Round'] = (quandl_gold_fridays['Close']/23).astype(int)` which is the vectorized equivalent to what you're trying to do.

Comment: it's better to just copy/paste the code into your question. that link may rot one day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the following line:

```
quandl_gold_fridays['Round'] = quandl_gold['Close'].apply(lambda x: int(float(x)/23))
```

Notice that you used **quandl_gold** on the right-hand side instead of **quandl_gold_fridays**. The date corresponding with your NaN is 2014-04-18, which was Good Friday (i.e. markets closed). There would be no corresponding value in quandl_gold on that date for the lambda to use, so it would be passed NaN.

To illustrate, try adding a cell with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.merge(left=quandl_gold.loc[:, ['Close']], 
             right=quandl_gold_fridays.loc[:, ['Close','Round']],
             left_index=True,
             right_index=True,
             how='right')
x.tail(10)
```

You'll notice the NaN in the "Close_x" column.